# Print Dynamic Error Array to Sheet

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm having troubles getting my Error array to print to a range. I'm fairly sure I'm resizing it incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I created a test add which just added garbage data from columns A and B, but normally AddPartError would be call from within various Subs/Functions, and then at the end of the main script process the array should be dumped onto a sheet. Here are the relevant functions:

```
Sub testadd()
For Each i In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
    Call AddPartError(i.value, i.Offset(0, 1))
Next i
tmp = PartErrors
PrintArray PartErrors, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[D1]
Erase PartErrors
tmp1 = PartErrors
PartErrorsDefined = 0
End Sub

Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, Cl As Range)
    Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), 2) = Data
End Sub

Private Sub AddPartError(part As String, errType As String)
    If Not PartErrorsDefined = 1 Then
        ReDim PartErrors(1 To 1) As Variant
        PartErrorsDefined = 1
    End If
    PartErrors(UBound(PartErrors)) = Array(part, errType)
    ReDim Preserve PartErrors(1 To UBound(PartErrors) + 1) As Variant
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens? do you get an error? or does nothing happen? Can you give some more information?

Comment: The values are assigned to PartErrors, but nothing is printed to the worksheet. No errors.

Comment: can you try `Debug.Print Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), 2).Address` in your PrintArray Sub.. Check your intermediate window and see if it matches what you're expecting. Also, how do you know that values are assigned to PartErrors? Where is PartErrors declared?

Comment: Sorry, both PartErrors and PartErrorsDefined is declared at the module level:
`Private PartErrors() As Variant
Private PartErrorsDefined`

Address is defined as $D$1:$E$11, which would be the expected range with 10 items in columns A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I did a bit of checking and the reason this doesn't work is because of your array structure of `PartErrors`

PartErrors is a 1 dimensional array and you are adding arrays to it, so instead of multi dimentional array you end up with a jagged array, (or array of arrays) when you actually want a 2d array

So to fix this, I think you need to look at changing your array to 2d. Something like the below

```
Private Sub AddPartError(part As String, errType As String)

    If Not PartErrorsDefined = 1 Then
        ReDim PartErrors(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As Variant
        PartErrorsDefined = 1
    End If

    PartErrors(1, UBound(PartErrors, 2)) = part 'Array(part, errType)
    PartErrors(2, UBound(PartErrors, 2)) = errType

    ReDim Preserve PartErrors(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(PartErrors, 2) + 1) As Variant
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, Cl As Range)
    Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 2), 2) = Application.Transpose(Data)
End Sub
```

NB. You also need to Transpose your array to fit in the range you specified.

Comment: That's what my problem was. Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @Methonis no problem. It makes things a lot easier to help if you provide code you can copy / paste and run. And your code did just that :)

Answer (score 0):

You code is a little hard to follow, but redim clears the data that is in the array, so I think you need to use the "Preserve" keyword.

Below is some example code you can work through to give you the idea of how it works, but you will need to spend some time working out how to fit this into your code.

Good luck!

```
Sub asda()

'declare an array
Dim MyArray() As String

'First time we size the array I do not need the "Preserve keyword
'there is not data in the array to start with!!!
'Here we size it too 2 by 5
ReDim MyArray(1, 4)

'Fill Array with Stuff
For i = 0 To 4
MyArray(0, i) = "Item at 0," & i
MyArray(1, i) = "Item at 1," & i
Next



' "Print" data to worksheet
Dim Destination1 As Range
Set Destination1 = Range("a1")
Destination1.Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1) + 1, UBound(MyArray, 2) + 1).Value = MyArray


'Now lets resize that arrray
'YOU CAN ONLY RESIZE THE LAST SIZE OF THE ARRAY - in this case 4 to 6...
ReDim Preserve MyArray(1, 6)
For i = 5 To 6
MyArray(0, i) = "New Item at 0," & i
MyArray(1, i) = "New Item at 1," & i
Next


'and let put that next to our first list
' "Print" data to worksheet
Dim Destination2 As Range
Set Destination2 = Range("A4")
Destination2.Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1) + 1, UBound(MyArray, 2) + 1).Value = MyArray


End Sub
```

Comment: The regular ReDim is only called once to initialize the array, much like in your example. ReDim Preserve is called on all subsequent ReDims. If you paste my code into a module (making sure to declare PartErrors and PartErrorsDefined at the module level), set a breakpoint at tmp = PartErrors, and run it on a sheet with data in columns A and B, you'll be able to see the populated data in the locals window does exist - it's not empty.